# Unrecognized selector sent to instance on custom init method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have an object called Communicator.

Communicator has a custom init method `-(id)initWithEmail:(NSString*)theEmail andPassword:(NSString*)thePassword andPlatform:(NSString*)thePlatform;`.

My app delegate has a Communicator as a member variable called communicator.

In `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I do this

```
communicator = [[Communicator alloc] initWithEmail:@"email" andPassword:@"password" andPlatform:@"mac"];
```

In the console it prints `-[Communicator initWithEmail:andPassword:andPlatform:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10064c4b0` twice.

The method exists and is defined. "communicator" is definitely a Communicator object. The project compiles with no warnings.

Communicator is defined in a custom framework that I made myself. I used otool and it says that the `initWithEmail:andPassword:andPlatform` method is in there.

It would seem that I've messed something up when building the framework but I have no idea what it could be. The project builds, links, and launches without a problem.
Is there some project setting that I might have messed up? Any other ideas?

Comment: Could be a subtle typo. Please copy and paste the actual method signature.

Comment: Also please copy and paste the entire exception message. You left out one vital character in front of the opening square bracket.

Comment: OT: Apple's recommendation for method naming is to not use "and" as a separator between arguments, and reserve it to indicate chronological flow, as in `takeTeacup:(Teacup *)cup spoon:(Silverware *)spoon andStir:(NSInteger *)seconds`.

Comment: @Jason: I know that. The member variable is declared just like this `Communicator *communicator;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some stuff set up wrong. Instead of dealing with Framework install paths on the custom framework, I just copied it to the frameworks folder. Of course I forgot that I did that and every time I made an update to the framework, it was going agains that old copy I stuck in the frameworks folder. This was super frustrating.